# Adding values to `std::vector<std::tuple<CustomClass, int, double>>` using implicit perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, perfect-forwarding, stdtuple

I have a `std::vector` of `std::tuple`s which store integral types along with a class which has no copy constructor. My aim is to add values to this vector without making any unnecessary copies of `MyClass` in the memory. Because, `MyClass` is going to store huge amount of data in my real application.

What I tried is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass()                   = delete;
        MyClass(const MyClass &)    = delete;
        MyClass(const std::wstring & str, float flt)
            : Text(str), Value(flt)
        {
        }

        std::wstring Text;
        float Value;

    private:
};

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[], wchar_t *envp[])
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<MyClass, int, double>> Items;
    Items.emplace_back(L"Entry0", 2.3f, 5, 5.7);
    Items.emplace_back(L"Entry1", 3.4f, 6, 6.8);
    Items.emplace_back(L"Entry2", 4.5f, 7, 7.9);
    for (size_t i=0; i<Items.size(); i++)
    {
        std::wcout << std::get<0>(Items[i]).Text    << L'\t';
        std::wcout << std::get<0>(Items[i]).Value   << L'\t';
        std::wcout << std::get<1>(Items[i])         << L'\t';
        std::wcout << std::get<2>(Items[i])         << std::endl;
    }

    _wsystem(L"pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2015 gives the following error somewhere inside the standard library file "xmemory0".

> 'std::tuple::tuple(std::tuple &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t [7]' to 'std::_Tuple_alloc_t'
>   xmemory0   657

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Would it be an option to change the type to `vector<pair<MyClass, tuple<int, double>>>`?

Comment: Or give `MyClass` a `std::pair<std::wstring, float>` constructor, maybe.